# Multiple SQL statements for a single array of hash insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am doing something like this to insert multiple records at the same time in my rails app.

```
VoteRecord.create(
  [
    { :prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "GE" },
    { :prospect_id => prospect.id, :state => "OH", :election_type => "PR" }
    ...
   ]  
)
```

When I check the log i see that the insert query is fired multiple times by sql. Is it possible to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [active record import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)  for bulk import,checkout wiki and example page.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but you should check out the activerecord-import project (for Rails 3) 
[github](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) More on this can be found here: [wiki](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki)

Comment: Duplicate! See Amar's answer.